# How to call one module inside other module in magento admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

how to put "news" module inside "Entry" Module. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your **News** menu as a children of **Entry** menu in `etc/adminhtml.xml` file of News module.

You can take an example of catalog menu.
Assume your **Entry module as a Catalog module** and assume your **News module as a Product module** in below file.

```
<menu>
    <catalog translate="title" module="catalog">
        <title>Catalog</title>
        <sort_order>30</sort_order>
        <children>
            <products translate="title" module="catalog">
                <title>Manage Products</title>
                <action>adminhtml/catalog_product/</action>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            </products>
        </children>
    </catalog>
</menu>
```